# R install_github produces error: command failed (5)

Tags: r, devtools

I am trying to install the package rpivottable via install_github.
When trying I get the error:

```
        Downloading github repo smartinsightsfromdata/rpivotTable@master
    Installing rpivotTable
    "C:/R/R-PORT~1/App/R-PORT~1/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore CMD INSTALL  \
      "C:/Users/..../AppData/Local/Temp/RStudioPortableTemp/RtmpyAFPYw/devtools1df857205157/smartinsightsfromdata-rpivotTable-4c7d219"  \
      --library="C:/R/R-Portable/App/R-Portable/library" --install-tests
Error: Command failed (5)
```

Rtools is properly installed, find_rtools returns TRUE.

I am running R on the Rportable version due to limitations on admin policies on the machine. In particular I had to set the PATH from R as I don't have access from Windows, but after installing and reinstalling the PATH contains the two paths to Rtools and gcc bins.

The information on my sessionInfo is here:

```
R version 3.1.3 (2015-03-09)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Australia.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Australia.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_Australia.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                      
[5] LC_TIME=English_Australia.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] shiny_0.11.1   devtools_1.8.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] bitops_1.0-6    digest_0.6.8    git2r_0.10.1    htmltools_0.2.6 httpuv_1.3.2    httr_0.6.1      memoise_0.2.1   mime_0.3        R6_2.0.1       
[10] Rcpp_0.11.6     RCurl_1.95-4.6  RJSONIO_1.3-0   rversions_1.0.0 stringr_0.6.2   tools_3.1.3     XML_3.98-1.1    xtable_1.7-4
```

I don't think the problem is related to the package specifically since before I had the same problem with htmlwidgets if try to install via install_github, and I managed to install it directly from CRAN to solve the problem.

I have checked the code of install_github but I can't find what generates the command failed(5) error message. I have got lost after going down a few levels in the call stack.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: have you tried just downloading the repo manually and then installing with the standard R tools? (R CMD build and R  CMD INSTALL)

Comment: I didn't but I have tried now... the package seems not to be downloaded to the path where the builder is looking for it... I guess the configuration of the machine (security policies) prevent it... Thanks for your comment.